# In football, do player wear the same jerseys that are sold to spectators?

Tags: football, uniform

In European football, in Paris-Saint-Germain for instance, or other Nike teams in general, and often in lots of european clubs, there are two types of jersey that are sold:

1. A "classic" jersey, at 85€
2. A "match" jersey, at 140€

It is clear that the PSG players don't wear in match the jersey at 85€ but do they wear the same jerseys that are sold at 140€? Or do they wear another one that is not sold and that could, for example, be ligther, more resistant or better in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Soccer.com](https://www.soccer.com/guide/authentic-vs-replica-do-you-know-the-difference/) article, on-field (authentic) jerseys are different then that sold to spectators (replica).

> Nike calls their authentic jerseys Vapor Match to note the technology that goes into what the pros wear on game day. They cost $164.99. ...
>
> The Vapor Match, worn by the likes of FC Barcelona, ***Paris Saint-Germain***, Chelsea and others is slim fit, made to it your natural body shape and stretch in every direction. The badges are heat pressed.
>
> The Nike replica, called stadium as that’s where you wear it, is also stylish and street-ready. These models cost $89.99. They has Dri-FIT technology and Nike Breath Fabric to keep you cool and comfortable. The badges are sewn-on.

The article also differentiate between authentic and replica jerseys of Adidas and Puma.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ram's answer, I would like to specify that even a "Match" jersey isn't *exactly* the same than the one wore by the pros.

Pros have several patches referring to the played game (e.g. UCL patch, "Fair Play" or "Respect"...) or to the former season winning (e.g. [Scudetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scudetto) in Italia).

One can still buy these patches by his own means, but it's usually not included when you buy a "match" jersey.